# Move element with scroll with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can i turn this Jquery Code into a angularJs directive :

http://jsfiddle.net/MMZ2h/4/

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("div").scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        $('img').animate({top: '-=10'}, 10);
    } else {
        $('img').animate({top: '+=10'}, 10);
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: 1. just copy into angular controller (use with id or class). 2. make a directive

Comment: Do you want to keep jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use selector here because link function provides the compiled DOM angular DOM. You can play with that DOM as you were doing in your code.
**Markup**

```
<div scroll-div>
   Content here
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('scrollDiv', function () {
return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        element.scroll(function (event) {
            var st = element.scrollTop();
            if (st > lastScrollTop) {
                $('img').animate({
                    top: '-=10'
                }, 10);
            } else {
                $('img').animate({
                    top: '+=10'
                }, 10);
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @sani Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what your markup looks like, what your app is called or, well anything else but something like this should work:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myScroll',
    ['$window', 'jQuery',
        function($window, $) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
                    $(elem).scroll(function (event) {
                        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
                        if (st > $scope.lastScrollTop) {
                            $('img').animate({top: '-=10'}, 10);
                        } else {
                            $('img').animate({top: '+=10'}, 10);
                        }
                        $scope.lastScrollTop = st;
                    });

                }
        };
}]);
```

Example markup:

```
<div myScroll>This is just some stupid text unworthy of being read, so please don't waste
    <br>your time reading this nonesense.
    <br>Hey! why are you still reading this garbage?
    <br>Stop reading now and start doing something useful, such as getting this leaf to move up
    <br>while you scroll this page.
    <br>On second thought, maybe just continue reading.
    <br>This might be more productive then whatever
    <br>it is you were doing before.</div>
```

**NOTE**: `restrict: 'A'` restricts the directive to Attributes on an element.
See [Angular Directive Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more info